# Conflict with my Mac user won't let me connect to my site's FTP

Tags: macos, terminal, network, ssh, ftp

I realize this may be a weird thing to ask and that it doesn't make much sense, so I will clarify the issue here. It is a very bizarre issue that I do not understand why is happening and I do not know how to fix.

Here's the scenario: My Mac's user name is `andyibanez`. I am also the owner of `https://www.andyibanez.com`. I want to configure my website to use a different subdomain for FTP, SSH, and all those goodies, called `ftp`, so my `ftp` host will be `ftp.andyibanez.com`. So I created the DNS settings and tried to use them.

Here's the weird thing, though: When I open the Terminal app and type `ssh andyibanez@ftp.andyibanez.com`, the operation fails *immediately*, it doesn't even try to connect to the internet. I know it doesn't because it fails as soon as I send the command by pressing the Enter key.

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ftp.andyibanez.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

All apps I have tried to use SSH and FTP have failed immediately. That includes Cyberduck and Transmit.

Trying to ping `ftp.andyibanez.com` doesn't work, either.

```
ping: cannot resolve ftp.andyibanez.com: Unknown host
```

At this point you may be thinking that I have misconfigured my DNS settings. Nope, I am 100% I didn't, for the following reasons:

- All operations in regarding that host fail immediately.
- I have actually tried a different computer (that doesn't have `andyibanez` as a user) and it worked fine. I was also able to connect fine using the Transmit iOS app.
- I set up another domain as `ftp.myotherdomain.com` with the same things as `ftp.andyibanez.com` and it works fine. I can connect to it with no problems.

Of course, I have the easy workaround that I can connect with this computer by setting a different subdomain or even using the naked domain. So I can connect to SSH. I am asking this because I am really curious as to why this happens.

Comment: Where did you create the DNS Settings? If you modified your Zone File, it may take a while for the changes to take effect. Also, try to change your DNS-Server to google (8.8.8.8) to see if there is a problem with your current DNS-Server Settings

Comment: I use Namecheap's DNS server for my configuration. Locally I connect to OpenDNSs DNS.

Answer (score 2):

What does `dig ssh.andyibanez.com` return to you? DNS is not immediate action and there is some TTL. If you did the DNS change and started trying immediately, you or your DNS provider has the records cached.

The easiest way is to way few hours and it will start work (I can resolve these hostnames from my place and initiate `ssh` connection).

Other way around is to [flush your local DNS cache](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202516), probably with something like this:

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

Comment: I should probably clarify that when I was working on the other site the DNS chances were almost immediate. I can connect to `ssh.andyibanez.com` because I configured it to be my workaround host for `ftp.andyibanez.com`. It's funny, but only `ftp.andyibanez.com` fails. Anything else I configure the DNS for works almost instantly.

Comment: @AndyIbanez: DNS caching is complicated, and can be very tricky to debug. It's entirely possible to get immediate updates on one client, and multi-hour delays on another (even identically configured client). That's why more direct probes like `dig` (which bypasses the client-side cache but not the server cache) can help isolate problems.